# Firebase event count increase but value is empty

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

I used Google's sample for log events in Firebase.

```
FirebaseAnalytics fba = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(getContext());
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("name", "value");
            fba.logEvent("event_name", bundle);
```

and it's working fine, but it just add counts and the value is always empty.

Comment: What exactly is your problem? What are you trying to achieve and what happens instead?

Comment: As I understand we use bundle to send some key/value as child of event
and event shown in console but another data that i put in bundle not show anywhere

Comment: Which another data that you are expecting to see? According to the documentation, custom events' parameters will not show up in the Developer account. Only the names of the custom events and aggregated data will show up https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/android/events

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems for using custom events , We must upgrade to higher plans and link firebase account with Bigquery to show detailed events

Comment: if that is the case, Google Firebase should mention in the console, to avoid confusing users.